# A better Hexagony template

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid

We once [made a Hexagony template without actually knowing it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104604/78410). But after a bit of experience with Hexagony, it becomes apparent that it is not enough; sometimes the source code is too short for the given hexagon, and you get totally unexpected results.

So I came up with an idea: a template that gives a hint when the code is too short.

For the background: [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony) detects the smallest hexagonal grid that fits the source code, and then fills each spot in the grid with each char in row-by-row fashion. E.g. the code

```
abcdefg@
```

contains 8 characters, and the smallest grid that can fit this is of size 3 (size 2 grid has only 7 spots)

```
  . . .
 . . . .
. . . . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

so the code above is laid out like this:

```
  a b c
 d e f g
@ . . . .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

Now, to ensure that the code being written is actually laid out on the hexagon of size 3, the programmer has to make sure that the code has at least 8 characters; in other words, at least one of the spots marked `*` must be occupied by a command:

```
  . . .
 . . . .
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
```

Math note: the number of spots in the hexagonal grid of size \$n \ge 1\$ is \$a(n)=3n(n-1)+1\$ ([A003215](https://oeis.org/A003215)). Since the Hexagony interpreter only has [hexagon sizes of 1 and higher](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony/blob/b674f59a0c9e10c1867bd9cf34f676ba89f0fc1c/grid.rb#L66), \$a(0)\$ is undefined for this challenge.

### Task

Given a positive integer `n`, draw a hexagonal grid like the one above so that

- the first \$a(n-1)\$ spots are drawn with one kind of marker (e.g. `.`) and
- the rest are drawn with another (e.g. `*`).

For \$n=1\$, it is allowed to output any of the two possible grids (single `.` or single `*`).

For output format:

- You can choose the two markers, but the two must be distinct and not a whitespace character.
- Extra leading and trailing whitespaces, and whitespaces at the end of each line are allowed, as long as it doesn't break the hexagonal layout.
- Outputting as a list of strings (lines) is OK.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
n=1
*
or
.

n=2
 . *
* * *
 * *

n=3
  . . .
 . . . .
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *

n=4
   . . . .
  . . . . .
 . . . . . .
. . . . * * *
 * * * * * *
  * * * * *
   * * * *

n=5
    . . . . .
   . . . . . .
  . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . .
 . . * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
   * * * * * *
    * * * * *
```

Comment: Bonus points for anyone who does this in Hexagony?

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 92 bytes

Outputs a leading newline.

```c
x,y,z;f(n){for(x=n,z=3*n*--n;~z;)printf(!y--?y=n-~n-abs(--x),"\n%*.s":z--<6*n?"* ":". ",x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoJAFIX3PsXtgjAzzhUiauE4@CJurDCEOoW28Ad9dRujRasD3@H8XORyr3Bb194OdnS1gp7qZ6t6Dzv6g4ERgVtGp19tg3etdoNIMXjIAqnOnRLpteUSsUk7zkaR/GRQsCHOOCW2vXbzGpL0qBooTVNEoZ/UhkCe9i5I7ukYNEm@Pv2mGD6@siVoF@B2zf2ZJUrwRuZoXj8)

Some ideas are drawn from [@Quentin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104627/88546) to the other hexagon challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 76 bytes

```
1-.#n.n.>.n.<0\;.'.* <ls"\# \, ?s".n3*.n1- *1+ e*
1+.n +"# ".~ rep \.n5* pad
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin)

For testing purposes:

```
1 10 .-> ( ; outln n\ out ).'
1-.#n.n.>.n.<0\;.'.* <ls"\# \, ?s".n3*.n1- *1+ e*
1+.n +"# ".~ rep \.n5* pad
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
1-.#n .n.> .n.< 0 \;.'.* <ls .;
  1+ .n + "# ".~ rep \ .n5* pad
( \# \, ?s ) .n3* .n1- * 1+ e*
```

- `1-.#n` input - 1 as \$n\$
- `.n.> .n.< 0` create palindromic range \$[0, n) \cup [n, 0]\$
- `\;.'` for each \$x\$...

  - `1+ .n + "# ".~ rep` repeat `#`  \$x+n+1\$ times
  - `\ .n5* pad` pad with spaces to \$5n\$
- `.* <ls` join stack with newlines
- `(...) .n3* .n1- * 1+ e*` execute \$3n(n-1)+1\$ times...

  - `\# \, ?s` replace first `#` with `,`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＮθＦθ«Ｐ^×*θ→→»‖Ｂ↓ＵＭ✂ＫＡ⁰±×⁶⊖θ¹.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49C8IwGIRn@ytCpzcSRUEc6uTH4lCR6izE9K0G81Hj24qIvz0GHB0O7rgH7tRVBuWliXHr2o52nT1jgDtfZI0PLBn2zgZlZ0i3QTuC4iTYUVt8QD7MBbvzRA5K3yMUlb5c6T9@sgobg4pWHRGGxryg2PinS1Up27W3VroaDkYrhD3ibWkMcMEmgu3wIgnhNzcXbIMqoEVHWKdjPEHTpHyc80WMszjqzRc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on my golf to @KevinCruijssen's Charcoal answer to the linked question, except at the very end I replace all but the last `6n-6` `*`s with `.`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>21</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
<‚εxŸ¨„1 ×û.c}`Sþ0.;
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Steffan*.

Outputs `1` for `*` and `0` for `.`, with \$n=1\$ being `*` (`1`) (thus \$a(0)=0\$).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//zzigJrOtXjFuMKo4oCeMSDDl8O7LmN9YFPDvjAuO///NA) or [verify the first 10 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/iquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC5en4ufy3edQw69zWiqM7Dq141DDPUOHw9MO79ZJrE4IP7zPQs/6vc2ib/X8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
<             # Decrease the (implicit) input-integer by 1
 ‚            # Pair it with the (implicit) input: [input,input-1]
  ε           # Map `y` over this pair:
   x          #  Double the current value (without popping it)
    Ÿ         #  Pop both, and push a list in the range [y,2y]
     ¨        #  Remove the last item to make the range [y,2y)
      „1 ×    #  Repeat string "1 " that many times†
          û   #  Palindromize the list
           .c #  Join the list by newlines, and pad leading spaces to centralize it
  }`          # After the map: Pop and push both the input'th and (input-1)'th hexagons
              # separated to the stack
    S         # Convert the (input-1)'th hexagon from a string to a list of characters
     þ        # Only keep the digits of these characters
       .;     # Replace each first digit occurrence in the input'th hexagon
      0       # to a 0†
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† Any other digits besides `1`/`0` could be used.

Comment: `DL+<` can just be `xŸ¨` for -1 byte. (That makes you beat Vyxal :()

Comment: @Steffan Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 machine code, 51 bytes

```
56 B8 20 C7 07 85 99 59 A8 AE 01 D1 75 02 F7 DA 51 F3 AA 89 F1 66 F3 AB 88 0F 59 29 D6 39 F1 75 E2 88 E0 6B CE 06 E3 0A FD AE 75 FD FE 4F 01 E2 F8 FC C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTdTtswFL62n@KsCClpC0q7FdKUbuLvEm2qkLYJepHaTmPkJlmcQArqDU@wiyHxIDzRHmTdcZqmRdrwRSyf7@/4R2F7U8aWS1/PwIJRw6L7UxVPfAUBDTyS5DqEVEuoxg4l@5N5JsApTtyqBL9//ZzFtyD8oo11t@ccnh52HdhQcVFTH6lyvBo5PdxC4PWobM@@fh6dwZfLEVylXI5NxLHb6/f7bm@T4Lzp87ghur0N8fktYr9fE59eGP/xX2Jvm5jECaSs@CfxePvAMqEz8FW5m3NDfN4inr/R49OLZr6eUOJzDoLhkQteUHIT3YOmJBLTcq3XV8cQS0UCOouNqLynUqTlBrhbAdX5MkVJtQ9KdD4x3CqFzZIt@U0kQDkrrdmKH1IiZ7mqKW04QBb63INAq4xT1fFI1X@p7lDCBYOT75fn9RW3OmNKVIwdGJgpToWHrWbUboA9oLex5BBYLPTTJug2yCiDCOt0R0ZM5VzAESbJeD/8SKkBZ76MLJs@oBdqIBU6V9lVr9MdD0ox9jofUBLEKVilGQyhM8DpaAguzq2WTQmqSWCttO0yj5AkRXpgNXaldx011tU80nIaCQ5lWjNBt5XMgHehVAKsAovNpDRGmzwzVFMcrl7oJ/Oij8GDYpWTZ9pqYIRZLWidex1d@CyUeI4s5sIrYR7DwxqHXaf7DfuaDy3rVVdNO7CvilZrbA8WULU0h3cm/fS9cakdrF0J5lVqu9yh6WexXP5hgfKnerk3O/iAH/x3DJEv1F8)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1), and takes the number \$n\$ in ESI.

In assembly:

```
f:  push rsi        #
    .byte 0xB8      # ┐mov eax, 0x8507C720 
    .byte 0x20      # │
l0: .byte 0xC7      # │               ┐mov DWORD PTR [rdi], 0xA8599985
    .byte 0x07      # │               │
    .byte 0x85      # ┘               │
    .byte 0x99      # ╴cdq            │
    .byte 0x59      # ╴pop rcx        │
    .byte 0xA8      # ┐test al, 0xAE  ┘
    .byte 0xAE      # ┘               ╴scasb
    add ecx, edx
    jnz s
    neg edx
s:  push rcx
    rep stosb
    mov ecx, esi
    rep stosw
    mov [rdi], cl
    pop rcx
    sub esi, edx
    cmp ecx, esi
    jne l0
    mov al, ah
    imul ecx, esi, 6
    jrcxz e
    std
l1: scasb
    jne l1
    dec BYTE PTR [rdi+1]
    loop l1
    cld
e:  ret
```

- ECX and ESI both start out being equal to \$n\$.
- At first, ECX is reduced by 1 at the start of each iteration, for the number of spaces at the start of the line.
- At first, ESI is increased by 1 at the end of each iteration, for the number of spots in the line.
- When ECX hits 0, at the middle line, those changes are reversed: from then on, ECX increases and ESI decreases. The `neg edx` instruction does this.
- EDX is initialised to 1 using the 1-byte `cdq` instruction (sign-extend from EAX). This requires the high bit of EAX to be 1; because of the way the overlapping instructions worked out, this necessitated using 0x85 (NEL) as a newline instead of 0x0A (LF). (Because TIO's output mechanism does not handle NEL, the additional code in the TIO demonstration converts NEL to LF.)
- The null terminator is added using `mov [rdi], cl` in the middle of the loop, taking advantage of ECX being 0 after `rep stosw` counts it down. This actually adds a null byte at the end of every line, but it is overwritten by the NEL except at the end.
- The final part of the code runs backwards through the string and modifies the last \$6(n-1)\$ spots.

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>110</s> 105 bytes

```
;=n+~1P;=c~1;=i+1*2nW+1=i-iT;O+*' '=xI>=x-n iFx~x'\';=j~2;W<=j+1j-*2n xI<c-**3n n*3n;=c+1cO'. \'O'* \'O''
```

100% can be golfed but I'm too lazy to do that lol.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhpc9pGGP7eXyGrqdEiIYN7TZBlT@I6HU8bnMZuPS2QsFotIEesiA6bFOS/7r67ulZcTr8wkvbZ99rnPZY7fI8jEnrzuMUClz4RH0eR8hvzJtP4IgyDUKGLmDI3UsTbMs0A73AY0fq6tKdAvU9Y7M2ex13HIcWzJQlYFIcJiYNQw2gZT73IjIIkJNTGKax489upF9NojgnV8vUZjslUO/qg9QfDQX8Qwfe0O9RX3/Y/DNiwqQ3Y6gVCzSOUzin9BKshjZOQKZLwfnu4WrHE99NMmGMQu42WPo0VbDsmXVCiSXBk5SL4Ftu28Rl/6MoQW3o2o8QB2zUMakyfskk8RQbukyFK4wAc99hkq1VpKsKh3Pz97uLa7g@tLFR/YT@hyyjGsUeUOT8FzUFLx9wIjzWGKN7jEHxoW/hEiMn1W1jXM/@ILb738dAsZFneWCMot4ekkq9pmDAR9jB4UBh9yBiRutRJJlu@7/BOCDGrRcD1kplDwx24YhFwr4PAp5jtAJarac6q3yEYIfZL4mWhWyNZlMy5dEOI@ujiGAPXMkclJVucyd@rfds8yd/roA03ig8yjH72uXk5AiseWI0ZocE481py4/BQMh74mD0VUeDCyxDkIdngT8H1Kptu3gxR/1Xrn2HzyOiUlMeHh/yAuUxNvVG5NpS6yWxeOjMqnHkh8jNFo9SPp5UrB5Wth4e4dmwTGafIuIM6MM3IPE@iqca/IitLlYveX5fvr3pvL3o39jLNE@bSpSxe48Bz7vdx69@PQ/7bbr38CCFYD4AQCsam@9jkcRCwqR4fsdUbe4DLQpTheKDAXG/CuBzJk36FGZbUzAzegeIZfB94rtI@4OdTWG5VCSrXZW30J/vEggemeKVlSqNmWmNUj7lwARXxlaL7tfQauPpmSCGgebpgtE6qfKHiFHZdiSvF/oozOpZKB0qhBu@Ft@rwWeLvhTfrcNe7l72slvhJ1A6hEPUWx1MTeMOIJPUI/N51SOo5ZiyIFVAFZ6I4X5R/aRioYGrg/k/dlcLv8LP6QHziB5K@efCwX18lfrU60PBJG32V883mV3hPF/OAcZLimAqDlDiA2sjoBPh2TxUwjoZgpL@jkpzI57az3pzWUDXiV7TvQUPcz3upepfE7@UlFWWc50JqJaSoILzdruWAysEaUvd1BiEvd/6ZUJJgBmZSscVUy2D8z11ycPi3IjrQHJ8NDqeQY2Op56iNIYI5LhpcD5tnaNA5Mo4FrXg0gFmOTCTQwIeVbIjBZjbccbDa4G2JrFYNtcEfUOVSNbTyogdWzTwGTHKVz0kAhKKMBAn/TN2u8mKJ09G2li7sr@eR0Wmj1aq9VrPyAWFfzeJOjHJArnCz9HBQpcsM6Zxi6D1yBXqG8eWotZfxJUo@VPiYd1fYhd3rL4x0cWqH9HPihVRTx5GKjCUfkcWSIy2Rqee7H@dhQGjEUW/@7J3fXF71rqve/AZqwL7WLLEkO2CYzEsxfUfqdOKkpVnVknh11hVZp69MdJQxhvJ5ms/H/MWF@dg9IcVs7Baz8dgWFpmFKVzZwXgHnd560LvZRMHhJJnxgePF0tU7qQJKlDH3EjqqwxupRbPAjlEqnTEPhEYMx6BrIwV8ImtjBRdn4@yZ4Rm1newZVEc22ZxdxQbNNM0SVVaWrIqrXHvsBUxT9VJqGR5HKUZOsRXrtmooqu6YmYyyi@vqRm26cu4oiU0vEvw1YFxKx7kqJaQTL4qpcBEtIbQd3quKC9LaXUJTe2CSMktgyHMgUReYxP4XBXqBQqY4hDeYWfyATaAmWRVB8NB2JI0QmLJzyUebJxncQDVHygMk155qjMruG9ZWGqi9QLnnkqFQJr7LbRUq3AOolVJW8YAjowyB@k41NGSf5lcyVTUc@3UyHtPQxL4fEA0GcDfgQcJaGxjRhoncAMo7cKVEDhj@ySI6uPoAGUe1DnRhsSJucibPrVsPEl8dMBUhYhMz8j24IbYNpVVN9kWlISiVLXufWVZr3WM/AF9/OH75w8uffj5@@VNTfA0xc4MZD5u8/0I1sH3KQ4Zroa0gjVcNDikTPQtvbpUjdzcw4KwwM5NkjsNgdg4MOA9cGDTzuxPqFubKx2mSHPcq5jObbORrYSSWP51nn/LLpfiVl0diuexDded2OKr@ITblBdGkC2@9ikvYg1KBuGvVL0A15O8lknssG1Ikk4z@hXPrtBzfasEuLItiN0hi8yGExg0CszxHBq7F7KouqNKaS1MHA3E9zMkGTDvbIb9gI0BQdytmxHvjNyNklDOTbIkOFOVFpDou3mhz32rOtzaQ/F6wDdncQPK@vA15tIEUt4EtyO82ZQbb7fywgRRT9xbkSYksqVJs4RNBuUXec7p7z2TXnrPde3jJ37rnsNyj4SKva//TnOXburXMWz27DXedzYy0pG3ZqrEtYLYEq9UWfqVdrUCldL2vJzI28/u5Y5f6nZrw21L4kndPq5a0FlpLt61kvsxEQNO3T/HWYJFN33@VNomgVXYbTu2SZvDyL70WFQwX/1JyIauVqtajdp0rcIWKYtMzqlzb3dRcgotWz8f6M6zDVFmYAB0O6USvTNJd3ourhvHYkCte/eoOOIhOUUVgYrnvH0MnfHp6@vGbJ8tm@mPnnWWTx45le3qnecxu9Y7ttbwb60pvNpSGvbg8tRctpnhvFo@LxqBh2XePx9btiX2nd@5asEFZXJ6QVrP5PZwg/IAwvUOuGqYyaFw1muK38R8)

[Test Suite up to n=10](https://tio.run/##lVhrV9s4Gv48@RXC22IrdkzCdDsLxnBahs5yhga20OHsJmmRZSUxdezUF0hJzF9nX/kq5wKdLzmJ9Oi96Xkvyi25IyENnGnU8nybPVGXhCH603NG4@gkCPwAsVnEPDtE6a95kgEuSBCy@r5wpkB9ir3ImbyMu4wCRiZz6nthFMQ08gOF4Hk0dkI99OOAMpMksONMr8dOxMIpoUzJ9yckomNl54vS6w/6vX4I68n@QF38o/el7w2aSt9bvMK4uYOTKWPfYDdgURx4SBDeaw8WCy923SQTZmnUbOO5yyJETEtnM0YVAY6NXAQ/YpomOeJf9kWIKXzXw9gC2xUCanSXeaNojDXSowOcRD447nijtVYlSRoOdPXfi5NLszcwslD9RdyYzcOIRA5FU34LioXnlr4SHmMIUbwjAfjQNshBKibXbxBVzfyjZrreIwO9kGU4Q4Xi3B6aCL4mQeylYQ/8e@Sx@4wRic2seLRmfYN3qRC92gRcN55YLNiAKzYB9973XUa8DcByN8lZdQbBCIhbEi8L3RLJwnjKpWupqK82iQhwLXNUULLGmfx3dW6dJ/nvOmjFjWJBhLHvLjcvRxDkgNXEo8wfZl4LbmxvC8YDH7NvRRS48DIEeUhW@FNwvcqmqw8D3HvX@t@guaN1SsqT7W1@wVymIl1JXBtO7HgyLZ25KZx5leZngm8SNxpXrmxVtm5vk9q1jUQcEnFbdWCSkXkah2OFr2IjS5WT7l@nn867H0@6V@Y8yRPm1GZetMSBl9zvkdbD1wH/bLf2vkIIlgOQCgVjk@fY5HAQsKken/SoM3QAl4Uow/FAgbnOyONyBE96FWZQUjMzeAOKZ/Cd79iovcXvp7DcqBJUrMvKzWfvm@ffe8gpLUNyzTT5ph7z1AVcxFeI7s/Sq2@rqyGFgObpQvAyqfKNilPEtgWuFOcrzqhEKB04gRr8LLxVh09i91l4sw63nTvRy2qL30TtEgpRH0k01oE3HhWk7oDfmy5JOiae50cIVMGdIOsHemCBL4Gpvv03dVcKX5MX9YH42PUFfVP//nl9lfjFYkshB238U843mz/hPZtNfY@TlEQsNQhFPtRGj42Ab3cMgXEsACPdDZXkQLy3jfXmsIaqEb@ifRca4vO8F6p3SfxuXlJxxnkupFZCigrC2@1SDkgcrGDpuc6QysudfyGU1J@AmSw9oktlMP7mKTE4fK2IDjTHF4PDKWSZROg5kjzAMMeF/ctB8wj3OzvabkorHg1gliUSCTTwYSUbYoieDXccLMm8LdHFQpZk/gVXLlVDKy96YNXE8YBJNvoe@0Ao5lE/5svM3kev5iS5WdfSU/vreaR12nixaC/VrHxAeK5mcSduckCucLX0cFClSw/YlBHoPWIFeoHx5aj1LONLlHipsJh3VzhF7MsfHt0niRmw77ETMEUahhLW5nxETrcsYYuOHdf@Og18ykKO@vC5e3x1et69rHrzB6gBz7VmgSXZBcNkXorpWUKnS29amFUNgVdH@2nWqQsd72SMYXye5vMx/2HDfGwf0GI2tovZeGimFumFKVzZ1nADnT460Lu9ESLBKJ7wgePV3FY7CQIlaMi9hI5q8UZqsCywQ5wId8wDoVDN0tjSSAFLdGms4OJMkn33yISZVvYdVIcmXZ1d0wOKruslqqwsWRWXuPbI8T1FUkupZXgsVIyc6VGimpKGJNXSMxllF1elldp0bt0yGulOmPJXg3EpGeaqUMBGThix1EU8h9B2eK8qHkhLbwlF6oJJaBLDkGdBos4IjdwfCHoBomMSwC@YWVzfG0FNMiqCkIFpCRohMGXnEq82TzJ4gSqWkAdYrD3VGJW9N4y1NJC6PrrjkqFQxq7NbU1V2FtQK4Ws4gHHWhkC6ULSFGwe5k8ySdIs8308HLJAJ67rUwUGcNvnQSJKGxjRholcA8pb8KTEFhj@zaAquHoPGceUDnThdCd9yek8t64dSHyp70kYU5PqoevAC7GtoVY12ReVhuJEtOxTZlmtdQ9dH3x9s7v3Zu/tb7t7b5vpakA825/wsInnTySNmIc8ZKQW2goiv5M5pEz0LLy5VZbY3cCAo8LMTJI@DPzJMTDg2Ldh0MzfTni/MFe8Tp3muHcRn9lEI9@nRhJx6Thbyh@X6ae4fZNul32o7twGR6X/pIfygqizmbNcxQXsVqkgfWvVH0A15FmJ5B6LhhTJJKJ/59w6LMe3WrALy8LI9uNIvw@gcYPALM@xRmoxO68LqrTm0qR@P30e5mQDph1tkF@wESB4fy3mhvfGxg3WyplJtEQFivIiUl0Xb7S5bzXnWytI/i5Yh2yuIHlfXofcWUGmr4E1yNerMv31dn5ZQaZT9xrkQYksqVIc4RNBeUQ8c7j5zGjTmaPNZ3jJX3tmuzyjkCKva//THOXH9muZt3jxGNm3VjPSEI5lu9q6gJkCrFZb@JN2sQCVwvO@nshEz9/nllnqt2rCr0vhc949jVrSGngp3daS@TQTAU3fPCRrg0VXff9DOJQGrbJbs2qPNI2Xf@FnUcFI8S8lF7JYSFI9ape5AjtVURx6QZVt2quaS3DR6vlYf0RUmCoLE6DDYZWqlUmqzXtx1TAeZbHi1Z/ugIPoFFUEJpa73i50wqenp05jt/Fr403jn423jd8a/2rsNTrtxpNhDtH7s/PjPxu/GKanPnYuDJM@dgzTUTvNXe9a7ZhOy7kyztWmjGRzdnpozloecj7MHmdyXzbM28dd4/rAvFU7ty04gGanB7TVbP4K9wsfIEzt0HNZR335XG6mn3LDMB9Qu3H979OzE@UQdTpIMdGDoqIOegAPwJLzz1cXn68QLMmeKcMqrB2/OztDw8Yv@Z4s/x8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes

```
‹"ƛdr‛a *∞øĊ⁋;÷Ǎ(n0øḞ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLlcIsabZHLigJthICriiJ7DuMSK4oGLO8O3x40objDDuOG4niIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.